# BASH: Convert a JSON value with control characters and escaped double quotes to printable plain text

Tags: json, bash

My task is to traverse through a couple of files with Bigquery SQL queries embedded as JSON value and output the files with just the SQL statement. The JSON value is within two double-quotes.
The query text in the JSON formatted values can hold different control characters like \n for newline, \t for tab, back tics `, single quotes ' and escaped double quotes ". Single tics and back tics are not escaped in the JSON value. The control characters in the JSON files should be converted to the printed value: \n and \t should be replaced with newline and tab character and " should be just " )
Example of the input file

```
...
--params='{
  "query": "CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE flemming.testing2 AS\nSELECT \"12\" as Test,\n-- This is a comment \"?=\" ^`\n            \"23\" AS Valid\n,  45 as name\n\n/** Another comment with a backslash  $ \\\" ´\" * , **/\nFROM flemming.testing ;\n\n"
}' \
...
```

and this is the desired output

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE flemming.testing2 AS
SELECT "12" as Test,
-- This is a comment '?=" ^`
            '23' AS Valid
,  45 as name

/** Another comment with a backslash  $ \" ´' * , **/
FROM flemming.testing ;
```

I have tried with sed commands for many days and looked for a standard tool to convert a JSON formatted value back to original text but without luck so far.

Comment: Use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

Comment: Your input contains `´\" *`; your expected output for that contains `´' *` — which has somehow transliterated `'` and `"`.

Comment: Try using [ANSI-C Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `jq` to process JSON in the shell. I saved your query as a json file `1.json`:

```json
{
  "query": "CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE flemming.testing2 AS\nSELECT \"12\" as Test,\n-- This is a comment \"?=\" ^`\n            \"23\" AS Valid\n,  45 as name\n\n/** Another comment with a backslash  $ \\\" ´\" * , **/\nFROM flemming.testing ;\n\n"
}
```

and ran the following command:

```sh
jq -r '.query' 1.json
```

`-r` stand for "--raw-output", it outputs the string without JSON formatting.

This was the output:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE flemming.testing2 AS
SELECT "12" as Test,
-- This is a comment "?=" ^`
            "23" AS Valid
,  45 as name

/** Another comment with a backslash  $ \" ´" * , **/
FROM flemming.testing ;
```

I think the double quotes around `23` are correct, as well as the double quote before `?=` and `*`.

Comment: Amazing, it was that simple. Thank you so much.